# How to do batchUpdate instead of update on Namedparameterjdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, jdbctemplate, batchsize

I am parsing a file and am creating a list of string elements that im inserting in to my table. Im trying to set a batch size of 5 rows inserted at a time and can't figure out how to use `.batchupdate` in place of `.update` in my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're currently calling [`update(String sql, SqlParameterSource paramSource)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource-).

The comparable batch version is [`batchUpdate(String sql, SqlParameterSource[] batchArgs)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource:A-).

So it seems pretty obvious, to do it as a batch, build an array, and make the call.

```
final int batchSize = 5;

List<SqlParameterSource> args = new ArrayList<>();
for (ZygateEntity zygateInfo : parseData){
    SqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource("account_name", zygateInfo.getAccountName())
            .addValue("command_name", zygateInfo.getCommandName())
            .addValue("system_name", zygateInfo.getSystemName())
            .addValue("CREATE_DT", zygateInfo.getCreateDt());
    args.add(source);
    if (args.size() == batchSize) {
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, args.toArray(new SqlParameterSource[args.size()]));
        args.clear();
    }
}
if (! args.isEmpty()) {
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, args.toArray(new SqlParameterSource[args.size()]));
}
```